# How To Parse String File Txt Into Array With C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a C++ program, but I am not familiar with C++. I have a `.txt` file, which contains values as follows:

```
0
0.0146484
0.0292969
0.0439453
0.0585938
0.0732422
0.0878906
```

What I have done in my C++ code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("Qi.txt");
    if(myReadFile.is_open())
    {
        while(myReadFile.good())
        {
            getline(myReadFile,line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        myReadFile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to make the output of the program an array, i.e.

```
line[0] = 0
line[1] = 0.0146484
line[2] = 0.0292969
line[3] = 0.0439453
line[4] = 0.0585938
line[5] = 0.0732422
line[6] = 0.0878906
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want your data stored as floating point numbers (not strings) you probably want to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

int main() { 
    std::ifstream in("Qi.txt");

    // initialize the vector from the values in the file:
    std::vector<double> lines{ std::istream_iterator<double>(in),
                               std::istream_iterator<double>() };

    // Display the values:
    for (int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++)
         std::cout << "lines[" << i << "] = " << lines[i] << '\n';
}
```

Just a quick note on style: I prefer to see variables fully initialized right when you create them, so `std::ifstream in("Qi.txt");` is preferable to `std::ifstream in; in.open("Qi.txt");`. Likewise, it's preferable to initialize the vector of lines directly from istream iterators rather than create an empty vector, then fill it in an explicit loop.

Finally, note that if you insist on writing an explicit loop anyway, you *never* want to use something like `while (somestream.good())` or `while (!somestream.eof())` to control your loop -- these are mostly broken, so they don't (dependably) read a file correctly. Depending on the type of data involved, they'll frequently appear to read the last item from the file twice. Usually, you want something like `while (file >> value)` or `while (std::getline(file, somestring))`. These check the state of the file immediately after reading, so as soon as reading fails they fall out of the loop, avoiding the problems of the `while (good())` style.

Oh, as a side note: this is written expecting a compiler that (at lest sort of) conforms with C++11. For an older compiler you'd want to change this:

```
    // initialize the vector from the values in the file:
    std::vector<double> lines{ std::istream_iterator<double>(in),
                               std::istream_iterator<double>() };
```

...to something like this:

```
    // initialize the vector from the values in the file:
    std::vector<double> lines(( std::istream_iterator<double>(in)),
                                std::istream_iterator<double>() );
```

Comment: Thank you for including the style notes. Very helpful.

Comment: What will the vector "lines" store when the iterator encounters a blank line?

Comment: I think one should `#include <fstream>` to compile.

Comment: @max: Yup. Corrected.

Comment: Noob question inside : What's the point of the line `std::istream_iterator<double>()` ? A comment would be really welcome. And thanks anyway for your nice answer.

Comment: @max: A default-constructed istream_iterator is basically "end of file"--that is, it'll compare equal to an iterator into a stream only when the stream has been read all the way to the end of the file.

Answer (score 5):

First you'll need a vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines; // requires #include <vector>
```

Then you'll need to take a string taken from the `getline` operation, and push it back into the vector. It's very simple:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(myReadFile, line);) 
{
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```

For an output operation, all you need is:

```
{
    int i = 0;

    for (auto a : lines)
    {
        std::cout << "lines[" << i++ << "] = " << a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hehehe. A vector is essentially a line. So you put the result of `getline` into the vector.

Comment: when I compile, I got the error message "warning: auto will change meaning in c++0x; please remove it"

Comment: @IbnuSyuhada Compile with `-std=c++11` and see what happens.

Comment: @IbnuSyuhada: He's intending the meaning of `auto` as defined in C++11. It sounds like you might want to update your compiler, though the proper flags may get it to interpret `auto` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string line;
ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open("Qi.txt");
if(myReadFile.is_open())
{
  for(int i=0;i<7;++i)
    if(myReadFile.good())
    {
        getline(myReadFile,line);
        cout<<"line["<<i<<"] = " << line << endl;
    }
    myReadFile.close();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Consider adding a bit of explanation.